# Subnet cannot access internet on CentOS 7 with VMWare

Tags: virtual-machines, linux-networking, centos7, vmware-workstation

Using VMWare Pro, I have two nodes with Centos 7 installed - one connected to my router with two network cards.  The other is another node I want to connect to the internet on a different subnet.  It looks like this:

```
192.168.1.1 - internet router
|
192.168.1.108 - (eno16777736) should route to the internet router
192.168.120.131 - (eno33554960) for subnet to pass traffic to 108
|
192.168.120.134 - Node on subnet
```

Lets call the one with two NICS "Gateway".  Currently Gateway has ip forwarding enabled.  iptables/firewalld/selinux are disabled currently to troubleshoot why this wasn't routing.

I was able to isolate it to the Gateway:

`ping -I eno33554960` returns Destination Host Unreachable whereas `ping -I eno16777736` reaches the server since it's on the same subnet as the internet router.

I thought CentOS sets up the route across NICs automatically, but I could be wrong....here's the route table in Gateway:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno167777336 proto static metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno16777736 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.108 metric 100
192.168.120.0/24 dev eno33554960 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.120.131 metric 100
```

I'm also wondering if it could be the VM setup.  NIC 1(internet subnet) is setup as Bridged (no replicate) and NIC 2 (the private subnet) is setup as VMNet2(Host-only) which was setup in the Virtual Network Editor.  "Connect a host virtual adapter" and "use local dhcp" are checked for this network.

Answer (score 0):

When you are pinging from the host in the 192.168.120.0/24 network, the internet router needs to know how to send replies back into that subnet, however it probably only knows about the network that it's connected to (192.168.1.0/24) and a default route to the internet.

You will need to either:

1. Configure a static route on your Internet Router to direct return traffic for the 192.168.120.0/24 network to 192.168.1.108 as the next hop.
2. Enable NAT on the eno16777736 interface on the "Gateway".

If your Internet Router is a typical ISP provided router, you will probably not be able to configure static routes and have to go down the [NAT route](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-firewall-ipt-fwd.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help - changing the VM to NAT on Gateway allowed the subnet NIC to reach the internet.  Now I'm trying to connect the second node to ping NIC 1 on the Gateway (ex pinging 192.168.120.131 from Node works but pinging 192.168.1.108 does not).  Do you think a route needs to be added on the Gateway to handle this?

Comment: To be clear, when I'm saying you need to enable NAT on the eno16777736 interface, I mean via iptables, not by changing the NIC type on the VM host itself.